# How old is the square root test for primes

Tags: math-history

It is well known that :

> if $n$ is an integer, $n\ge2$, having no divisor $d$ such that $1<d\le\sqrt n$, then $n$ must be prime.

**My Questions :**

Since when do we know this result ?

To whom should we attribute it ?

Any precise references would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably this method was already known in then antiquity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A Brief History of Factoring and Primality Testing B. C. (Before Computers)* by Richard Mollin ([PDF link](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~moira/mat331-spr10/papers/2002%20MollinA%20Brief%20History%20of%20Factoring.pdf)) makes two attributions.

To Ibn al-Banna, in application to the sieve of Eratosthenes:

> Ibn al-Banna (ca. 1258-1339) appears to have been the first to observe that, in order to find the primes less than $n$ using the sieve of Eratosthenes, one can restrict attention to prime divisors less than $\sqrt n$.

To Fibonacci (in his *Liber Abaci*, first published in 1202), in application to primality testing:

> In this work, Fibonacci gave an algorithm to determine if $n$ is prime by dividing $n$ by natural numbers up to $\sqrt n$. This represents the first recorded instance of a deterministic algorithm for primality testing.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting to see that there is no evidence of any earlier knowledge. Euclid, for example, had begun to penetrate the concept of prime number, but this property cannot be found in the *Elements* (book VII).